# How do i convert the following xml based spring bean to java annotation based beans?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

```
 <bean id="string.message.service" class="com.ce.indiabringsService">
 <constructor-arg ref="com.ce.indiabrings.consumer" />
 <constructor-arg ref="com.ce.indiabrings.value.function" />
 </bean>
```

I want to convert this to java annotation based bean (@Bean).

Comment: what have tried so far?  please go through with some tutorials

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm

Answer (score 0):

1. create a method in configuration class
2. Construct mentioned object and return.
3. Annotate the method with `@Bean`

---

```
@Bean
public com.ce.indiabringsService getindiabringsServiceBean(){
    return new com.ce.indiabringsService(consumerObj,functionObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class with `org.springframework.context.annotation @Configuration` annotation.

Then use @Bean annotation on a method and return appropriate bean object.

```
@Bean
public com.ce.indiabringsService getMessageService(){
    return new com.ce.indiabringsService(com.ce.indiabrings.consumer,com.ce.indiabrings.value.functioncom.ce.indiabrings.consumer);
}
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

One more option

```
   @Bean
public com.ce.indiabringsService getIndiabringsService(com.ce.indiabrings.consumer  
 consumerBean,com.ce.indiabrings.value.function functionBean){
 indiabringsService indiabringsServiceBean =new indiabringsService();
 indiabringsServiceBean.setConsumer(consumerBean);
 indiabringsServiceBean.setFunction(functionBean);
 return indiabringsServiceBean;
}
```

you can inject `indiabringsService` by using `@Autowired`.

for creating `indiabringsService`  bean, Internally  spring will automatically inject consumer  and function  beans while creating indiabringsService  bean.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfigurationClass {
    @Bean
    public com.ce.indiabringsService getIndiaBringsService() {
        return new com.ce.indiabringsService(com.ce.indiabrings.consumer,com.ce.indiabrings.value.functioncom.ce.indiabrings.consumer);
    }
}
```

And then you can autowire it as follows:

```
@Autowired
private com.ce.indiabringsService myIndiaBringsService;
```